# "We can't preview this area of your page because it's in an IFRAME" google ad error on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ads, adsense

While reviewing the auto ad settings, I am getting the below error in my wordpress site.  "We can't preview this area of your page because it's in an IFRAME". How to sort out this issue

[image]